# Jfrog artifactory access server time out

Tags: artifactory, yum

We configured Artifactory 5.5.1 by using yum install using default derby db able to access with derby db.

When we changed to external db postgres, I not able to access Artifatory, access server is timed out after 60000 miliseconds.

Do we need to do any additional configuration changes?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: no... we are not using proxy

Comment: What do you see in the logs (Artifactory or/and Tomcat logs)

Comment: in artifactory logs after 60000 milli seconds , access server is timing out.